# Formulário PHP não envia email

Tags: php, html, forms, sendmail

Estou quebrando a cabeça com um formulario e não consigo fazer o submit funcionar.
O layout e campos estao OK:

```
    <div class="container-fluid">

                <div class="d-flex align-items-baseline justify-content-between">

                    <!-- Title -->
                    <h1 class="h2">
                        Diário Oficial - Cadastro de Publicações
                    </h1>

                    <!-- Breadcrumb -->
                    <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
                        <ol class="breadcrumb mb-0">
                            <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="javascript: void(0);">Pages</a></li>
                            <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Cadastrar Publicações - Diário Oficial</li>
                        </ol>
                    </nav>
                </div>

                <div class="row justify-content-center">
                    <div class="col-lg-10 col-xl-9 col-xxl-7">

                        <form class="needs-validation" novalidate>
                            <ul class="nav nav-pills steps mb-7 mt-n3 w-75 w-xxl-50 mx-auto" id="wizard-tab" role="tablist">
                                <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                                    
                                </li>
                                
                                
                            </ul>

                            <div class="tab-content" id="wizard-tabContent">

                                <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="wizardStepOne" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="wizardTabOne">
                                   <form action="enviar-demanda.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                    <!-- Card -->
                                    <div class="card border-0 py-6 px-md-6">
                                        <div class="card-body">
                                            <h2 class="text-center mb-0">Cadastrar publicação</h2>
                                            <p class="text-secondary text-center">Utilize o formulário abaixo para enviar materiais para publicação.</p>

                                            <div class="mb-3">
                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <div class="col-md">
                                                        <label  class="form-label">Entidade </label>
                                                        <select class="form-select" id="entidade" required autocomplete="off" data-select='{
                                                                    "placeholder": "Selecione..."
                                                                }'
                                                                data-option-template='<span class="d-flex align-items-center py-2"><span class="avatar avatar-circle avatar-xxs"><img class="avatar-img shadow-sm" src="./assets/images/flags/1x1/[[value]].svg" /></span><span class="text-truncate ms-2">[[text]]</span></span>'
                                                                data-item-template='<span class="d-flex align-items-center"><span class="avatar avatar-circle avatar-xxs"><img class="avatar-img shadow-sm" src="./assets/images/flags/1x1/[[value]].svg" /></span><span class="text-truncate ms-2">[[text]]</span></span>'>
                                                            <option value="" label="Selecione"></option>
                                                            <option value="prefeitura">Prefeitura de Nova Luzitânia</option>
                                                            <option value="camara">Câmara Municipal de Nova Luzitânia</option>
                                                
                                                            
                                                        </select>
                                                    </div>

                                                    <div class="col-md">
                                                        <label name="responsavel" class="form-label">Responsável </label>
                                                        <select class="form-select" id="responsavel" required autocomplete="off" data-select='{
                                                                    "placeholder": "Selecione..."
                                                                }'
                                                                data-option-template='<span class="d-flex align-items-center py-2"><span class="avatar avatar-circle avatar-xxs"><img class="avatar-img shadow-sm" src="./assets/images/flags/1x1/[[value]].svg" /></span><span class="text-truncate ms-2">[[text]]</span></span>'
                                                                data-item-template='<span class="d-flex align-items-center"><span class="avatar avatar-circle avatar-xxs"><img class="avatar-img shadow-sm" src="./assets/images/flags/1x1/[[value]].svg" /></span><span class="text-truncate ms-2">[[text]]</span></span>'>
                                                            <option value="" label="Responsável"></option>
                                                            <option value="rogerio">Rogério Março Morais</option>
                                                            <option value="tereza">Tereza Gama</option>
                                                            <option value="luizf">Luiz Fernando</option>
                                                            <option value="agemyr">Agemyr Pereira</option>
                                                            <option value="admilson">Admilson Máximo</option>
                                                
                                                            
                                                        </select>
                                                        <div class="invalid-feedback">Selecione a categoria do material</div>
                                                </div> <!-- / .row -->
                                            </div>


                                                    <div class="col-md">
                                                        <label name="categoria" class="form-label">Categoria</label>
                                                        <select class="form-select" id="categoria" required autocomplete="off" data-select='{
                                                                    "placeholder": "Selecione..."
                                                                }'
                                                                data-option-template='<span class="d-flex align-items-center py-2"><span class="avatar avatar-circle avatar-xxs"><img class="avatar-img shadow-sm" src="./assets/images/flags/1x1/[[value]].svg" /></span><span class="text-truncate ms-2">[[text]]</span></span>'
                                                                data-item-template='<span class="d-flex align-items-center"><span class="avatar avatar-circle avatar-xxs"><img class="avatar-img shadow-sm" src="./assets/images/flags/1x1/[[value]].svg" /></span><span class="text-truncate ms-2">[[text]]</span></span>'>
                                                            <option value="" label="Categoria da Publicação"></option>
                                                            <option value="leis">Leis</option>
                                                            <option value="decretos">Decretos</option>
                                                            <option value="portarias">Portarias</option>
                                                            <option value="licitacoes">Licitações</option>
                                                            <option value="contratos">Contratos</option>
                                                            <option value="relatorios">Relatórios</option>
                                                            
                                                        </select>
                                                        <div class="invalid-feedback">Selecione a categoria do material</div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div> <!-- / .row -->
                                        <div class="mb-3">
                                                <label name="arquivo" class="form-label">Arquivo </label>
                                                <div class="dropzone text-center px-4 py-6" data-dropzone>
                                                    <div class="dz-message">
                                                        <img class="avatar avatar-xxl mb-3" src="https://d33wubrfki0l68.cloudfront.net/dab0efca2a3dfb58288f0abf1251e668b2f56229/96c61/assets/images/illustrations/upload-illustration.svg" alt="...">
                                
                                                        <h5 class="mb-4">Arraste e solte os arquivos aqui</h5>
                                
                                                        <p class="mb-4">or</p>
                                
                                                        <!-- Button -->
                                                         <input class="btn btn-sm btn-gray-300" type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
                                                        
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <span class="form-text">São suportados arquivos de até 50mb.</span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                            </div>
                                    

                                    

                                        
                                </div>

                               
                                      <div class="card-footer">
                                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">

                                                <!-- Button -->
                                                <a class="btn btn-light" data-toggle="wizard" href="#wizardStepOne">Cancelar</a>

                                                <!-- Button -->
                                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ><a>Enviar</a>
                                            </div>
                                            </div>
                                    </form> 
                                        
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div> <!-- / .row -->
            </div> <!-- / .container-fluid -->
```

o enviar-demanda.php também está Ok (inclusive enviando vazio se chamar a URL direto )

```
<?php
//Variáveis

$nome = $_POST['entidade'];
$email = $_POST['responsavel'];
$telefone = $_POST['categoria'];
$opcoes = $_POST['fileupload'];
$mensagem = $_POST['msg'];
$data_envio = date('d/m/Y');
$hora_envio = date('H:i:s');

//enviar

  // emails para quem será enviado o formulário
  $emailenviar = "diario@meugoverno.com.br";
  $destino = $emailenviar;
  $assunto = "Envio de Demanda | Nova Luzitânia";

  // É necessário indicar que o formato do e-mail é html
  $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
      $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
      $headers .= 'From: $nome <$email>';
  //$headers .= "Bcc: $EmailPadrao\r\n";

  $enviaremail = mail($destino, $assunto, $arquivo, $headers);
  if($enviaremail){
  $mgm = "E-MAIL ENVIADO COM SUCESSO! <br> O link será enviado para o e-mail fornecido no formulário";
  echo " <meta http-equiv='refresh' content='10;URL=contato.php'>";
  } else {
  $mgm = "ERRO AO ENVIAR E-MAIL!";
  echo "";
  }
?>
```

O problema está na hora de enviar os dados pra o enviar-demanda.php...
Por algum motivo, ao clicar em enviar ele simplesmente atualiza a pagina ao inves de rodar o .php.

Obs. Iniciante PHP.

Answer (score -3):

Você tem 2 forms, um dentro do outro.  Retire o primeiro form e deixe apenas o que tem o action.
(será necessário também retirar o ULTIMO /form)

Além disso, você PRECISA colocar o NAME em cada elemento input (input, select, textarea e o que mais existir de elementos de formulário).   Você está definindo apenas o ID, mas o NAME é necessário para o envio do form.